# Scanf and gets in c

Tags: scanf, gets

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    char c[20],s[20];
    scanf("%s",c);
    scanf("%s",s);

    //gets(s);

    printf("%s\n%s",c,s);
    return 0;
    }
above code output is:

harsh
is
```

But if I use gets() as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    char c[20],s[20];
    scanf("%s",c);
    gets(s);

    printf("%s\n%s",c,s);
    return 0;
}
```

for this output I got:
harsh

```
My input was
harsh
is a good boy
```

Why is these change in output?
will the same problem we encountered is in case of scanf("%d") with %d format specifier?

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: @SunSparc i have edited my question with the input